# Transfer a file from local server to another using Python library - Paramiko

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I want to transfer a file from a local server (that'll contain the code and file) to a remote server preferably using `ssh`. Here's the code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('Servername', port = 135, username='username', password='password')
print "connected successfully!"
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
print sftp
sftp.put('G:\TestDocument.txt','G:\TestDocument.txt' )
sftp.close()
print "copied successfully!"

ssh.close()
```

But I get this error:

> No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Python27/testtransfer.py", line 5, in 
>       ssh.connect('Servername', port = 135, username='username', password='password')   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 392, in
>   connect
>       t.start_client(timeout=timeout)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 545, in
>   start_client
>       raise e SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Can you tell me why am I receiving this error? I have purposely used port 135 because port 22 is closed on the target server and 135 (among others) is open.

You can even suggest some other way in which I can transfer files from one server to another using Python.

Comment: Does the *ssh* command work fine with the SSH server?

Comment: Well, it does throw an error while trying to connect to the destination server via SSH. I think it is due to lack of ssh server being set up on the server. Can you suggest any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
```

the error usually means the remote service was not a ssh service. try to make sure the service on port 135 is actually ssh.

And what's the OS on your server? Windows? if so you may need to setup a 3rd-part ssh server on your server. In my opinion if you need to copy files from windows to windows ftp is a much simpler solution. python has a built-in lib `ftplib`.

Comment: yeah, both the servers are Windows. I'd prefer not to install ssh server on the destination server. I'll, instead, try the ftplib library as you suggested, and get back to you.